# Compute an integral using some assumptions on derivatives

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Consider the functions

- $\mu: \mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow (0,1]$, where $\mathbb{R}^+$ denotes the extended set of real numbers $\geq 0$.
- $s_1: \mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow (0,1]$.
- $s_0: \mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow (0,1]$.

**Assumption 1:** the function $\mu$ is monotone increasing and differentiable at each point of its domain. Moreover, there exists a value $x^*$ in the domain of $\mu$ such that
$$
\frac{\partial \mu({\bar{x}})}{\partial x}\geq 0 \text{ and }\mu({\bar{x}})<1 \text{ for  }\bar{x}<x^*
$$
$$
\frac{\partial \mu({\bar{x}})}{\partial x}= 0\text{ and }\mu({\bar{x}})=1  \text{ for  }\bar{x}\geq x^*
$$
where $\frac{\partial \mu({\bar{x}})}{\partial x}$ denotes the derivative of $\mu$ evaluated at $\bar{x}$.

For example, the function $\mu$ may look like
[image]

**Assumption 2:** for each $(\bar{x}, \bar{y})\in \mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{R}^+$, it holds that
$$
\frac{\partial \log(\mu(\bar{x}))}{\partial x}= \frac{1}{s_1(\bar{x},\bar{y})}\times \Big[ \frac{\partial s_1(\bar{x},\bar{y})}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial s_0(\bar{x},\bar{y})}{\partial y}\Big]
$$

**Assumption 3:**

(a) For each $\bar{x}< x^*$, for each $\bar{y}\in \mathbb{R}^+$
$$
 \frac{\partial s_1(\bar{x},\bar{y})}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial s_0(\bar{x},\bar{y})}{\partial y}\geq 0
$$

(b) For each $\bar{x}\geq x^*$, for each $\bar{y}\in \mathbb{R}^+$
$$
 \frac{\partial s_1(\bar{x},\bar{y})}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial s_0(\bar{x},\bar{y})}{\partial y}=0
$$

---

**Claim to show**

By integrating assumption 2 over $\mathbb{R}^+$, one gets that for each $\bar{y}\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and for each $t\in \mathbb{R}^+$
$$
\mu(t)=\exp\Big( - \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{1}{s_1(x,\bar{y})}\times \Big[ \frac{\partial s_1(x,\bar{y})}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial s_0(x,\bar{y})}{\partial y}\Big] dx \Big)
$$

**My attempt to prove the claim:** for each $\bar{y}\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and for each $t\in \mathbb{R}^+$, we integrate assumption 2 over $[t,\infty)$ and get
$$
\int_{t}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial \log(\mu(x))}{\partial x}dx= \int_{t}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{s_1(x,\bar{y})}\times \Big[ \frac{\partial s_1(x,\bar{y})}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial s_0(x,\bar{y})}{\partial y}\Big]dx\\
$$
that is
$$
- \log(\mu(t))+\overbrace{\log(\mu(\infty))}^0=\int_{t}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{s_1(x,\bar{y})}\times \Big[ \frac{\partial s_1(x,\bar{y})}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial s_0(x,\bar{y})}{\partial y}\Big]dx\\
$$
that is
$$
\mu(t)=\exp\Big(-\int_{t}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{s_1(x,\bar{y})}\times \Big[ \frac{\partial s_1(x,\bar{y})}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial s_0(x,\bar{y})}{\partial y}\Big]dx\Big)\\
$$

---

**Question:** The source where I am taking the claim from adds to the proof the following observation "*the constant of integration is determined by using Assumption 3 (a)*". What does this mean? Where am I using Assumption 3 (a) to show the claim?